# Is it possible to show loading message in django admin when deleting objects?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have added some code in the pre_delete signal that deletes the images from aws s3 bucket.

Because of this, delete is taking more time which would obviously happen.

But I want to show some loading message till the object deletes and redirect to the model tabular view again.

How can I add that loading message ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do that with Django itself. You will need knowledge of a language which runs in the user's browser such as JavaScript